# One-way delete delete Django Channels thread

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-channels

I'm trying to make it possible for users to delete a thread with another user from their inbox.

I've followed the Django Docs `DeleteView` although this may be totally wrong.

views.py

```
class InboxView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    template_name = 'chat/inbox.html'
    context_object_name = 'threads'
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Thread.objects.by_user(self.request.user).order_by('-timestamp')
        # by_user(self.request.user)

class ThreadView(LoginRequiredMixin, FormMixin, DetailView):
    template_name = 'chat/thread.html'
    form_class = ComposeForm
    success_url = '#'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Thread.objects.by_user(self.request.user)

    def get_object(self):
        other_username  = self.kwargs.get("username")
        obj, created    = Thread.objects.get_or_new(self.request.user, other_username)
        if obj == None:
            raise Http404
        return obj

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = self.get_form()
        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not request.user.is_authenticated:
            return HttpResponseForbidden()
        self.object = self.get_object()
        form = self.get_form()
        if form.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        thread = self.get_object()
        user = self.request.user
        message = form.cleaned_data.get("message")
        ChatMessage.objects.create(user=user, thread=thread, message=message)
        return super().form_valid(form)

class ThreadDeleteView(DeleteView):
    model = Thread
    success_url = reverse_lazy('inbox')
```

models.py

```
class ThreadManager(models.Manager):
    def by_user(self, user):
        qlookup = Q(first=user) | Q(second=user)
        qlookup2 = Q(first=user) & Q(second=user)
        qs = self.get_queryset().filter(qlookup).exclude(qlookup2).distinct()
        return qs

    # method to grab the thread for the 2 users
    def get_or_new(self, user, other_username): # get_or_create
        username = user.username
        if username == other_username:
            return None
        # looks based off of either username
        qlookup1 = Q(first__username=username) & Q(second__username=other_username)
        qlookup2 = Q(first__username=other_username) & Q(second__username=username)
        qs = self.get_queryset().filter(qlookup1 | qlookup2).distinct()
        if qs.count() == 1:
            return qs.first(), False
        elif qs.count() > 1:
            return qs.order_by('timestamp').first(), False
        else:
            Klass = user.__class__
            user2 = Klass.objects.get(username=other_username)
            if user != user2:
                obj = self.model(
                        first=user,
                        second=user2
                    )
                obj.save()
                return obj, True
            return None, False

class Thread(models.Model):
    first        = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='chat_thread_first')
    second       = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='chat_thread_second')
    updated      = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    timestamp    = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    objects      = ThreadManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.id}'

    @property
    def room_group_name(self):
        return f'chat_{self.id}'

    def broadcast(self, msg=None):
        if msg is not None:
            broadcast_msg_to_chat(msg, group_name=self.room_group_name, user='admin')
            return True
        return False
```

html thread page with delete button

```
<!-- Delete Thread -->
          <form action="{% url 'chat:thread_delete' user.username %}" method='post'>  {% csrf_token %}
            <button type='submit' class='btn btn-light'>
              <i class="fas fa-trash-alt" style="color:royalblue"></i>
            </button>
          </form>
```

urls.py

```
app_name = 'chat'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', chat_views.InboxView.as_view(), name='inbox'),
    re_path(r"^(?P<username>[\w.@+-]+)", chat_views.ThreadView.as_view(), name='thread'),
    re_path(r"^(?P<username>[\w.@+-]+)/delete/", chat_views.ThreadDeleteView.as_view(), name='thread_delete'),
]
```

I keep getting the error

```
TypeError at /messages/userthree/delete/ cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object
```

which is being caused by `views.py` lines

```
self.object = self.get_object()
obj, created    = Thread.objects.get_or_new(self.request.user, other_username)
```

Comment: have you tried printing out "other_username"?

Comment: Yes it prints the logged in user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue here is that you have a return statement in your `get_or_new()` method that is not returning a tuple:

```
if username == other_username:
    return None
```

That causes the view to fall over because it's expecting to unpack a tuple into two variables. Returning a tuple should resolve:

```
if username == other_username:
    return None, None
```

Comment: Thank you, I see your point. After I change the method to return a tuple and calling the `DeleteView`, the url changes from the `ThreadView` url `http://127.0.0.1:8000/messages/newuser3` where `newuser3` is the other user to the `DeleteView` url `http://127.0.0.1:8000/messages/trilla/delete/` where `trilla` is me, or the logged-in user. Then I get a `404 not found`. Is this error happening because the `DeleveView` url is being configured improperly?

Comment: I've changed the `DeleteView` url to `{% url 'chat:thread_delete' thread.second %}` which doesn't throw any errors but still leaves the thread in tact and does not redirect to `inbox`

Comment: Are you able to post the whole of `views.py`? It seems that when `obj` is None the view is redirecting to a URL which is failing to look up.

Comment: The `DeleteView` form seems to be going to the right URL however it stays on the `../username/delete/` URL after `request.POST`

Comment: Ok the issue is that when the current user tries to delete their own thread, then `username == other_username` is `True` and we return `None, None`. That then causes a 404 from  `if obj == None: raise Http404`.

Comment: I'm not getting a 404 error though, nothing is happening on the page, it's just staying on the thread and refreshing the page

Comment: That's why I ended up changing the form action to `{% url 'chat:thread_delete' thread.second %}` instead of `{% url 'chat:thread_delete' user.username %}`